# Sql Query does not return the wanted value

Tags: mysql, sql

I am executing the following query

```
SELECT * FROM `temp` WHERE date_of_approval > "16-12-2015"
```

I want to get all record where the date is greater than "16-12-2015" but it displays all rows which are greater that "16" and not greater than "16-12-2015"

Comment: What is the datatype of `date_of_approval`?

Comment: before being able to answer this correctly, you will need to describe the column date_of_approval

Comment: it is a varchar but I perfomed the following query to convert it to date


update temp set date_of_approval=str_to_date(date_of_approval,'%d-%b-%Y')

Comment: Are you able to change your design?  You shouldn't be storing dates as strings, that's why there is a DATE data-type.  And if you have no choice but to store them as strings, then you should be using `'YYYY-MM-DD'` *(Because then alphabetic sorting of your string would match date order as well.)*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your table you store the date in the `dd-mm-yyyy` format so it is compulsory to convert into standard date format first then its compare with dates.

```
SELECT * FROM `temp` 
WHERE STR_TO_DATE(date_of_approval,'%d-%m-%Y') > STR_TO_DATE('16-12-2015','%d-%m-%Y');
```

OR

```
SELECT * FROM `temp`
WHERE STR_TO_DATE(date_of_approval,'%d-%m-%Y') > '2015-12-16';
```

Comment: what is data type of date_of_approval  column name ?

Answer (score 1):

My recommendation.  Always use ISO standard date formats.  These are accepted by most databaes:

```
SELECT t.*
FROM `temp` t
WHERE date_of_approval > '2015-02-16'
```

Also, use single quotes for string and date constants in SQL statements.  This is the standard delimiter for strings.

Comment: If only the Ops hadn't stored dates as strings.